# Grouping on Part of MySQL Datetime Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought this was working as it was giving results of the current (and only) entries on the day I was testing it but now that there are entries for several days, the results are not what I need or expected.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateField, '%M %h, %Y') AS `Date`, SUM(NumberCount) AS Counts 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateField, '%M %h, %Y') 
ORDER BY `Date`
```

is giving

```
March 04, 2019  2 
March 06, 2019  2 
March 11, 2019  3
```

while the table contains

```
2019-03-07 18:15:05 1
2019-03-07 18:21:58 1
2019-03-08 16:45:05 2
2019-03-08 23:19:00 1
2019-03-08 23:19:01 2
```

so I expected

```
March 07, 2019  2
March 08, 2019  5
```

Any ideas how to get the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `date` function.  Do you really need to format the date as a string?

```
SELECT DATE(DateField) AS `Date`, SUM(NumberCount) AS Counts 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY DATE(DateField) 
ORDER BY `Date`;
```

If you do use `DATE_FORMAT()`, don't include the hours where the day of the month should be.  You would presumably want:  `''%M %d, %Y'`.

Comment: Thank you, I had discovered the error before these answers arrived. I had h rather than d for the day. Yes, I do need the date formatted as the datetime field contains the time and grouping by it raw will also group by the time.

Comment: @DonP . . . "these answers"?  There is 1, it is 12 minutes before the one you posted, and it has essentially the same answer.

Comment: I was including the comments as answers. Don’t know about the 12 minutes but didn’t show up until after I submitted my comment and the page refreshed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops! Found the problem as I had the wront format code for the day. It should be

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateField, '%M %d, %Y') AS `Date`, SUM(NumberCount) AS Counts 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateField, '%M %d, %Y') 
ORDER BY `Date`
```